# This app references non-public selectors ... base64EncodedString dataFromBase64String

Tags: ios, cordova

I am getting this warning when submitting an iOS binary to Apple:
"This app references non-public selectors in Payload/x.app/x: base64EncodedString, dataFromBase64String"

I do not get a warning during the build in xCode.

I am using xCode 5.0.2 and Phonegap 3.3.

I don't know if Apple will reject the binary for this reason, but I don't want to wait to find out.  Also, I like to resolve all warning errors the "right" way.

I have found other people having similar issues (different third party libraries) and it seems their solution is to get updated third party libraries.  I am already using the latest phonegap and there has been plenty of time for this to have been resolved, so I suspect this problem is unique to something I am doing.

I have greped by project and the two symbols are referenced here:

```
Cordova/NSData+Base64.h:+ (NSData*)dataFromBase64String:(NSString*)aString;
Cordova/NSData+Base64.h:- (NSString*)base64EncodedString;
```

My two questions are:
1) Will Apple reject this binary because of this warning?
2) How can I resolve this warning message the "right" way?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question....

Upon further investigation we determined the problem was that we only
included libCordova.a in the project.  This worked okay when testing
in simulator and on device, but gave the above warning on submission
to the appstore.

The solution to avoid the warning on submission was to copy all the
source code for libCordova.a into /platform/ios.  That source code
originated from the "cordova create" command.